# How do you change what a command does in the terminal in linux?

Tags: linux, terminal, command

For example: I might want to change the output of "pwd" to something that says: "This is your directory:" instead of just listing the directory.

In my case, I want the command "nemo" to do "nemo `pwd` " instead. (Nemo is a file manager)

Comment: You could use aliases: http://www.linfo.org/alias.html ?

Comment: As franiis mentioned, something like `alias nemo="nemo \$(pwd)"`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an alias

```
alias nemo='nemo `pwd`'
```

or, you can create a function

```
nemo() {
    /path/to/nemo `pwd`
}
```

(full path is needed, otherwise the function would call itself)

or, create a file somewhere in the $PATH named nemo and make it executable (`chmod u+x nemo`) containing

```
#! /bin/bash
/path/to/nemo `pwd`
```